# Javascript: Select option based on its contents

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Basically this, but in pure javascript:
[How to get 'value' of select tag based on content of select tag, using Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346257/how-to-get-value-of-select-tag-based-on-content-of-select-tag-using-nokogiri)

I have a select list with a lot of countries/states, and I want to be able to select one based on what is between the `<option>` tags.

```
<option value="4783">Argentina</option>
```

(I know I could use the value, but each one is a random mesh of numbers, so I would have to collect each individual one - not economical)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit painful, but in pure JavaScript:

```
for(var i=0,sL=mySelObj.length;i<sL;i++){
  if(mySelObj.options[i].text == myValue){
    mySelObj.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: painful in that you need to iterate over the list... meaning that if the desired value is the last item and there are 100's of items you have to check each before selecting the final option.  Where possible I would always try and pre-select the value at the server where "hopefully" determining the selected option at code generation time is easier.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you meant painful in comparison to other client-side solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Now that querySelector is available in most browsers you can use:

```
document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = 
    document.querySelector('option[value=4783]').index;
```

Comment: If you know which browsers you need to support, you can check the support matrix for querySelector at http://caniuse.com/queryselector.

Answer (score 1):

Just 10 years late, but let's look at a new age solution.

If you are working in ES6+ here is a simple "one liner" to do the trick.

If you require broad compatibility, use a transpiler or another solution.

```
let $select = document.querySelector('select[name="countries"]');
let compareValue = 'Argentina';

$select.value = [...$select.options].filter(option => {
    return option.innerText === compareValue;
})[0].value;
```

The true one-liner expression:

```
$select.value = [...$select.options].filter(option => option.innerText === compareValue)[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textContent` property lets you see what's inside the tag. Off my head and without testing, that should work:

```
function selectByDisplayValue(selectTag, displayValue)
{
    var options = selectTag.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        if(options[i].textContent == displayValue)
        {
            options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
}
```

Where `selectTag` is the DOM object of your `<select>` tag, and `displayValue` is the display value of the option you want to select (for your example, "Argentina" it would be).

Comment: `textContent` is a DOM Level 3 method that is not supported by IE (and some other minor or older browsers). For `Option` objects you can use `.text`, which goes way back to JavaScript 1.0.