# Selecting an option in a dropdown menu based on node value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to set the value of a dropdown list in jQuery (or Javascript) based on the node value?

```
 <select name="ddlProperty">
        <option value="1" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="2">Animal Kingdom</option>
        <option value="3">Epcot</option>
        <option value="4">Hollywood Studios</option>
        <option value="5">Magic Kingdom</option>
        <option value="6">Downtown Disney</option>
</select>
```

I'd need to set the option of Magic Kingdom, so something like:

```
$("#ddlLocation").val("Magic Kingdom")
```

So that Magic Kingdom would become the selected item, that doesn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: You may also need to set the ID attribute on the <select> tag. Other than that follow Nick's answer.

Comment: There are multiple accepted duplicates for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937134/javascript-select-option-based-on-its-contents/2937177#2937177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the *value* (not text!), do that using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#ddlProperty").val("5");
```

If you don't have that, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to find and set the selected `<option>`, like this:

```
$("#ddlProperty option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "Magic Kingdom"
}).attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: and the older selected? you have to disable the older!

Comment: @CuSS - Only if it's a `<select multiple>`, not the case here :) Even then, only if you didn't want both selected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    options = box.options;

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i){
    if(options[i].text == val){
        options[i].selected = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ddlProperty > option").each(function(i, elem) {
    if($(elem).text() == "Magic Kingdom") {
        $('#ddlProperty').val(elem.value);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And next time please make a proper example where the element has an id and that ID matches the ID in your code. I've spent about 5 minutes checking for an error until I've noticed the ID being different...

http://jsbin.com/ikibi3/2

Comment: He has name, not ID ("<select name="ddlProperty">")

Comment: Selecting elementy by ID is probably faster, besides that he uses an ID is his javascript code. So don't downvote a perfectly correct answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
myselect="Magic Kingdom";
$("select[name='ddlProperty'] option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == myselect) {
        $(this).attr('selected', true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('selected', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Proper indentation would be nice.

Comment: explain me with another words please, my english is bad :(